# i want C++ code that will look for a file recursively in a directory, open it write data, save and close it

Tags: visual-c++

i want C++ code that will look for a particular file recursively in a directory and sub directories, open the file write some data at particular location and save the file in the same location and close it. i don't want list of files.
Can someone please help me in doing that??

Answer (score 0):

**I want c++ code that...**

First of all, this is not one of those sites. If you want some pointers in doing this, as far as I know, these will be useful.

[FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) to go over the directory/subdirectories.

[ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) to open the file and read its contents.

[ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) to write your required data and save it.